# How to check if a textbox has a line from a TXT File with C#

Tags: c#, textbox, .net-4.5, streamreader

It's simple what I'm trying to do; when I click a button, my app should check if `textBox1.Text` has a line from a text file.

**Note:** I don't want to check if textbox has all the text file in it, just to see if it has a LINE from it.

I tried this with no success:

```
 private void acceptBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(usersPath);
        string usersTXT = sr.ReadLine();
        if (user_txt.Text == usersTXT)
        {
            loginPanel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in Advance - CCB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string usersTXT = sr.ReadLine();
```

Reads exactly one line. So you are only checking if you match the *first* line in the file.

You want [`File.ReadALlLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which also disposes the stream correctly, which you aren't):

```
if (File.ReadAllLines(usersPath).Contains(user_txt.Text))
{
}
```

That reads all the lines, enumerates them all checking if your line is in the collection. The only downside to this approach is that it always reads the entire file. If you want to only read until you find your input, you'll need to roll the read loop yourself. Do make sure to use the `StreamReader` in a `using` block if you take that route.

You can also just use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (thanks @Selman22) to get the lazy enumeration version of this. I would go with this route personally.

Implemenation that shows this at: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,675b2259e8706c26

Answer (score 1):

```
if (File.ReadAllLines(path).Any(x => x == line))
{
    // line found
}
```

Replace `x == line` with a case-insensitive check or `Contains` if you want.

Comment: Good suggestion, note that `ReadAllLines` *always* reads the entire file (see my answer) so it could be non-performant if the file is large and the input is close to the top.

Comment: @Bradley Indeed, `ReadLines` is better in this case. However, there is also the question of whether this piece of code executes only every once in a while, or many times in sequence. If the latter - better read the file only once.

Comment: True. Of course, at that point you would need to store off the results anyways, which modifies the OP code quite a bit. Excellent point though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Contains() function on the string:

```
private void acceptBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(usersPath);
    string usersTXT = sr.ReadLine();
    if (user_txt.Text.Contains(usersTXT))
    {
        loginPanel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the bigger problem of only checking the first line in the file.